# How to save image in my device image library folder from my app document folder in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, image

I am receiving some image from web-service and store them into my app document folder. Now I have create an image library with my app name in iPhone device. Now. I want to show the images in this image library.

For saving the system image I am using this code -

```
[self.library1 addAssetURL:url toAlbum:@"My_App_Name" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                if (error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
                }
            }];
```

but this is not work when I get the url of my document folder image. Help me out or gave any solution.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS5** includes new API in the `AssetsLibrary` framework, which afford you the chance to manage your app’s own photo album inside the user’s photo library.

I think it is easy peasy. Your app should create an `UIImage` and will just need to pass it to the below method along with the album name and a block to handle.

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image
         toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName
withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock;
```

You can see more details [**here**](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/)