# How to give name for each and every picture before it saved in photo gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone programming. Can any body tell me that how to give name to each and every picture in photo gallery.i want save picture with particular name.

Please can any body tell me. Thanks

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195282/how-to-save-image-in-my-device-image-library-folder-from-my-app-document-folder/13195381#13195381

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code..

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourImageName.png"];

NSError * error = nil;
[imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return;
}
```